# Detecting 'Fold' of a webpage without loading it in a browser

Tags: javascript, java, python, html

Is it possible to detect `Fold` of a webpage without actually loading it in Web Browser ?

Say I have got 5 URLs, and I wish to know the fold position for these 5 URLs without loading them. More like a batch operation.
Can this be done using `Java/Javascript/Python ?`

Comment: what is `fold` position?

Comment: It is the point on a web page at which users have to scroll down. Above the fold is the portion of a Web page that is visible in a browser window when the page first loads.  The portion of the page that requires scrolling in order to see content is called "below the fold."

Comment: @aks Detect where? In a browser? At server? With a plug-in? Somewhere else?

Comment: @aks It should depend on the browser window size right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add more details or image to describe your problem.

Comment: IDK if this can be helpful here but have a look at phantomjs: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: you never know what the height of a browsers viewport is. Depends on windows size, resolution etc. So the answer is simply: no.

Comment: @Teemu - Detect in a server/with a plug-in. Say, set a flag in a script if an image found Above the fold.

Comment: @dunder - Correct. But, the browser window size will come as input to the App which will detect the fold based on the window size.

Answer (score 0):

A 'Fold' is more or less a design principle from back in the days, when responsive wasn't a thing yet. Nowadays I wouldn't care too much about the 'fold', but ask yourself the question: 'why bother about the fold?'.

A great article you (or your designer) should read: http://iampaddy.com/lifebelow600/

*Having said that...*

The 'fold' is relative to the browsers window height. On a mobile device, the fold can be as small is 320px, whereas full screen on a 27" screen the fold can be somewhere around 1400px.

If your question is: 'How can I detect the Y-position of a particular element on a given resolution without loading it in a browser?', you should reconsider the term 'browser'. The browser is the part that renders your HTML/CSS to some visual eye candy. Most browsers you now render direct to the screen (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc).

However... there is also such a thing as a 'headless' browser. These are browsers that don't render to the screen, but do provide functionality to interact with the page (as in: take screenshots and stuff). In that case I would suggest you take a look at [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Casper JS](http://casperjs.org/). Those are great packages that allow you to load one or more pages by script and take a screenshot of it, or you can read out the top offset of a DOM element by plain and simple JavaScript.

Phantom JS example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  // Take screenshot:
  page.render('screenshot.png');
  // Get offsetTop of the footer in the page:
  var offset = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('.footer').offsetTop;
  });
  console.log('Footer offset = ' + offset);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Hope this helps you somewhat.